# After filtering a dataset based on some condition I want to display all the data in java spark

Tags: apache-spark

I want to filter a dataframe and accordingly replace the data but after that I want to display all data. How to achieve this in java spark?

Below is the outputdf dataset

```
name   color
abc    red
apple  red
grapes green
lemon  yellow
```

I filtered the dataframe in the below way

```java
String colcondition = outputdf.col(color).equalTo("red");
Dataset<Row> df = outputdf.filter(colcondition);
df.show();
```

```
name    color
abc     red
apple   red
```

After filtering I'm replacing the data

```java
outputdf = outputdf.withColumn("newcol", functions.regexp_replace(outputdf.col("color"), "red", "blue"));
```

but this will show only 2 columns. I want all the rows in a dataframe.

```
name     color
abc      blue
apple    blue
grapes   green
lemon    yellow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#when-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.Object-)-`otherwise` functions

```java
outputdf = outputdf.withColumn(
    "newcol",
    when(colcondition, regexp_replace(outputdf.col("color"), "red", "blue"))
        .otherwise(outputdf.col("color"))
);
```

The value of the `newcol` column will be:

- `regexp_replace(...)` if `colcondition` is true
- `col("color")` (the previous color) if `colcondition` is false

---

In your case it can be simplified with

```java
outputdf = outputdf.withColumn(
    "newcol",
    when(colcondition, lit("blue")).otherwise(col("color"))
);
```

because `colcondition` is already checking that the color is red.

Comment: This solution is working perfectly but in my case colcondition is of string datatype. How to convert it to Column ? @vinsce

Comment: @Nandini are you sure your `colcondition` is String? The `equalTo` method returns a Column (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#equalTo-java.lang.Object-). However if it is a String expression you can convert it using `functions.expr(String)`

Comment: when I try to read arabic charcters from db using java spark they are getting replaced with ? any idea @vinsce